# data is not binding in sublime text using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app="notesapp">
<head>   
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

    NAME:<input ng-model="name" type="text"> <br/>

    Hello: <span ng-bind="name"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is issue with this can explain in details?

Comment: data is not binding whatever i typed in text box

Comment: Can you show your JS code? Where is your controller linked?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

For making small code like this work, we can actually define an empty ng-app.
Eg: `<html ng-app = "">`

If you however want to define ng-app with some value, we need to load that ng-app in javascript. It can be done in a separate js file or in the same html file with `<script></script>` tag. Please see below:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('notesapp', []);
</script>
```

Please close the script tag in your head. Also angular needs ng-app for its functioning. Please use ng-app on the tag which encloses your angular content.

```
<html ng-app="notesapp">
<head>   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('notesapp', []);
</script>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

    NAME:<input ng-model="name" type="text"> <br/>

    Hello: <span ng-bind="name"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, as you know, Sublime is just an editor. It has nothing to do with angular. Cheers.

Comment: ng-app was already defined above, plus there's still no controller defined.

Comment: @Seonixx: Thanks, But the post didn't have it initially. It is edited after or approximately around the same time I have posted my answer. This doesn't actually need a controller to be defined. ng-app alone solves the problem of OP.